# X11 Fowarding - Popup Dialogs are Popping Up on the Remote Server Instead of Locally

Tags: debian, ssh, x11

What is the trick to getting all dialogs of a remote application opening up locally?

I'm testing out X11 forwarding on a variety of applications and have been successful in getting those remote application's main window to run in local windows. However, "upon clicking anything within the remote application that produces an additional dialog window" (like a file navigation dialog), the new window doesn't open locally. However, if I log into the remote machine (which does have a desktop of its own), I can see that these dialogs have indeed launch into the desktop of the remote system (instead of launching into local windows).

How can I get the entire remote application to launch into local windows (not just the main window)?

Comment: Could you give a concrete example of a program that does this, and give more details about your system(s)? What you describe is not typical of my experience with X forwarding. Dialogues windows are visible on the client for me.

Comment: One example is Brave browser, that I have installed on a remote system via flatpak. From the local computer I run `ssh -X user@192.168.0.2 flatpak run com.brave.Browser`. This launches the remote Brave into a local window, but if I hit ctrl-o (to open a file with brave), that dialog doesn't pop up locally (it instead pops up on the remote system's desktop). The local system is Debian 11 and the remote system is [Ubuntu Unity](https://ubuntuunity.org/) 20.04.@frabjous

Comment: I highly suspect this is a flatpak sandboxing issue. I just tried normal brave and could open file dialogues, etc., over ssh with X forwarding without an issue. I don't use flatpaks so I can't provide a good answer but googling turns up discussions with some suggestions that may or may not be applicable; one of then involves using `flatpak run --socket=x11`. No clue if that'll help in your case.